# How to arrange images 3x3?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have nine images and if I have to arrange them 3x3,which means 3 rows and 3 columns. What would be the best way of doing it? Should I be using CSS?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562737/what-ways-can-i-put-images-in-a-grid-like-format

Comment: I will have a look at it

Comment: Don't forget to choose an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**3x3 Grid of images**

This css allows you to:

1. centers images vertically
2. centers images horizontally
3. allows images of various sizes
4. smaller than the grid size images keep original size, to not have the blurred images
5. bigger images get resized to the desidered value
6. that can simply be changed in the 3th part of the css with setting the `max-width` & `max-height`
7. and obiovsly it keeps the aspect ratio

This is achieved using `float-left` & the `line-height` trick;

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid3x3">
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/240/300"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/280/300"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/210/140"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/240/200"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/300"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/700/300"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid3x3{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 clear:both;
}
.grid3x3>div{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 float:left;
 line-height:100px;
 text-align:center;    
}
.grid3x3>div>img{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 max-width:80%;
 max-height:80%;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/c4gb8/

extra styling..

http://jsfiddle.net/c4gb8/1/

and javascript click handler

http://jsfiddle.net/c4gb8/2/

Answer (score 1):

using ul li

```
<ul>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T4wSJ/1/)

Comment: What if I need to click on the image and it needs to pop-out with a transparent background? Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML -

```
<div>
 <div class="row1">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
 <div class="row1">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
 <div class="row1">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
</div>

<div>
 <div class="row2">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
 <div class="row2">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
 <div class="row2">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
</div>

<div>
 <div class="row3">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
 <div class="row3">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
 <div class="row3">
     <img src="" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS -

```
.row1,row2,row3
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: What if I need to click on the image and it needs to pop-out with a transparent background? Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row3">
    <img src="#"  />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
</div>
```

css

```
   <style>
            .row3 img  {
                width:33%;
                height:33%;
                float:left;
                display:inline-block;
                border:solid 1px red;
            }
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sprite sheet. That will arrange in a regular grid. Sass will do this easily or you can use css.

[try online](http://sass-lang.com/try.html)

[css sprite generator](http://cssspritegenerator.net/howto.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to arrange all your website in a clean way, you can take a look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Otherwise, other solutions are better.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GKboI/) inspired by bootstrap logic.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row3">
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/400/300"/>
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/300/400"/>
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/350/400"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/250/400"/>
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/400/250"/>
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/440/400"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row3">
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/200/230"/>
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/430/400"/>
     <img class="col1" src="http://placekitten.com/400/430"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.row3{
  width:20%; /*the size you want*/
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:5px; /*Adjust it how you want*/
  margin-bottom:5px; /*Adjust it how you want*/
}

.col1{
  width:32%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:auto;
}
```

**Result with lovely kittens :3 :**

[image: Result with lovely kittens :3]

Comment: If you think that Bootstrap’s better than a clean HTML/CSS layout solution for this standard problem, than this is for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'll modify my response. Bootstrap is better if you want to arrange all your website with.
Sorry for my bad answer.

Comment: This would definitely be helpful :)

Comment: And as you can see, you can add more row, it will stack under the others. Try it yourself with the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GKboI/)

Comment: Yes I will give it a try :)