# Display items in 3 columns and 3 rows using css

Tags: css, laravel-blade

How can I make a 3x3 display of data? I am displaying data using foreach loop and this is the output:
[image]

This is my blade.php code

```
<div class="coupon_div">
            @foreach($coupons as $coupon)
            <div class="column coupon_col">
                <div class="coupon_cont pad">
                    <div class="coupon_details">
                        <h3 class="column_title coupon_title">
                            <span class="bullets">◼ </span>
                            {{ $coupon->name }}
                        </h3>
                        <p class="column_text coupon_text"> {{ $coupon->description }} </p>
                        <button class="btn_gold btn-coupon" type="button" name="button" onclick="window.open('{{ $coupon->file_path }}')"> Open </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

my css

```
.coupon_div {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.column {
  width: 345px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.coupon_col {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.coupon_cont {
  width: 345px;
}
.coupon_col .pad {
  padding: 0;
}
.coupon_details {
  padding: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
```

If I display 3 items only, it has the proper spacing. My expected output is somehow like this:

[image]

How can I possibly attain this result using css? because as the result shows, it displays data in 1 line only. I found some almost the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004091/how-to-arrange-images-3x3#answer-23004743) but somehow can't make it work.

Comment: You can use CSS [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the your answer :) I have figured it out. I just removed some part of `coupon_div` class from:

```
.coupon_div {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

To:

```
.coupon_div {
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

And added some checking:

```
<div class="column coupon_col {{ $key % 3 == 1 ? 'addmargin' : '' }}">
```

So if the item is on the 2nd, 5th and 7th, it will have a margin to its other 2 items.

```
.addmargin {
  margin: 0px 15px;
}
```

With this now, I'm able to get my desired result.